# Full screen mode doesn't take up full space in android default browser

Tags: android, cross-browser, default-browser

This problem is specific to the default browser present on android devices.

I have a webpage which runs in full screen mode by enabling it through javascript.
The window.innerHeight gives me the correct height of full screen which i set to the outer container.

But the problem is when the display goes to full screen mode the browser screen doesn't take up the full screen and there is white patch that is left at bottom which is equal to the height of the address bar on the top.
(See image below - check closely for the bottom white space)

This results in my html content being hidden since the height of the outer container is still the full screen height.

I have tested the issue in S3 and HTC ONE X.

[image]

Comment: show the `xml` code. I think the layouts are not given weights properly or try `android:fillViewport="true"` this by keeping it in the layouts. Might be useful

Comment: Which xml code?. This is a simple webpage iam trying to access in the default browser in full screen mode.

Comment: Why don't you just use `WebView` - thank way you can control all the aspects of the visualization?

Comment: go to `settings --> manage apps --> all--> browser/internet --> clear data` this may work

Comment: @Kartheek. that doesnt help.